# how click grid view of images in android

Tags: android

hi i have code for grid view of images and when i click each image of grid it open empty layout
but i want when i click the first image so open it with bigger size i mean call the same image that i clicked
this is the code of main

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class fitgridview extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fitgridview);
        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity2.class);

                // Pass image index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the code of myAdapter java class :-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by lenovo on 06/08/2016.
 */
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        mItems.add(new Item("Red",       R.drawable.ic_menu_camera));
        mItems.add(new Item("Magenta",   R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery));
        mItems.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.ic_menu_manage));
        mItems.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.ic_menu_send));
        mItems.add(new Item("Green",     R.drawable.ic_menu_share));
        mItems.add(new Item("Cyan",      R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow));
        mItems.add(new Item("Red",       R.drawable.ic_menu_camera));
        mItems.add(new Item("Magenta",   R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery));
        mItems.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.ic_menu_manage));
        mItems.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.ic_menu_send));
        mItems.add(new Item("Green",     R.drawable.ic_menu_share));
        mItems.add(new Item("Cyan",      R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow));

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int i) {
        return mItems.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return mItems.get(i).drawableId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

        Item item = getItem(i);

        picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }

    private static class Item {
        public final String name;
        public final int drawableId;

        Item(String name, int drawableId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.drawableId = drawableId;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the SquareImageView java class :-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by lenovo on 06/08/2016.
 */
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
    }
}
```

how can i call each image when i click it ? what should i write in SingleViewActivity2 to do what i wnt
 help me and thanks alot

Comment: Can you show the second Activity code so that we know what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the adapter only holds a list. You add objects **from the Activity** and pass in the list there.

In code,

```
// Fields 
private List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
private MyAdapter mAdapter;

// onCreate
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, mItems);
gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now, if you'd instead extend `ArrayAdapter<Item>` instead of `BaseAdapter`, you could take advantage of some useful methods. For example,

```
mAdapter.add(new Item(...));
```

Now, it's recommended you research how to do `public class Item implements Parcelable`, which is outside the scope of this answer.

Once you have that, you can pass `Parcelable` objects between Activities

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity2.class);

            // Pass image item 
            i.putExtra("item", mAdapter.getItem(position));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object from activity to adapter and then render.

currently you are creating and rendering object from adapter it is an programming practice.

when you pass object from activity then you can pass object with intent to next activity and you will achieve your requirement.

this the only way to your problem.

Comment: Not quite, the object needs to be passed though the click listener to the second activity